# Autoware Auto - Base docker image build

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have recently started working on Autoware Auto opensource code. And I am having trouble understanding how the Base docker image is built.
As per the given documentation, we directly download the executable from [here]($ wget https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/ade-cli/uploads/f6c47dc34cffbe90ca197e00098bdd3f/ade+x86_64).

I am interested know which dockerfile is being used to build the base docker image and also the where exactly the build process starts.

Kindly excuse if the question is too basic.

Thank you, 
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370164/autoware-auto---base-docker-image-build/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2021-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The docker images are built during a job on gitlab. You can have a look at the gitlab-ci file [here](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml).
Have a look at the lines `24` and `36` for the docker build commands.

The docker files used for the build are located in the [AutowareAuto/tools/ade_image](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/tree/master/tools/ade_image)
 directory in the repo.

Also you can have a look at the [container registry](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/container_registry) to see the built docker images.

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2021-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-01-25**:
Thanks for the answer @Mackou. I will have a look and come back if any queries.

**Comment by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) on 2021-05-26**:
How can we change the base image?